# Why is the font not changing when I select the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I select the cell I print the position in the array, and it prints correctly in the console, but when I try to change the font to bold to indicate that the cell was selected nothing changes.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: cellsort = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! cellsort
    cell.type.font = UIFont(name: "System-Bold", size: 17)
    cell.typeselected.hidden = false
    print("selected")
    print(sort[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: You need to reload your cell to get the changes effected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are changing the font on a different instance of `UITableViewCell`, not the one that was selected.

You should only use `dequeue...` inside the data source method `-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That method is used to configure a new cell on demand (based on your data model), and pass it to the table view for display.

Instead, use the method of UITableView: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (don't confuse with the data source method!). It gives you the actual cell that is on screen, or nil if the corresponding row is off screen. Source: [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

**Edit:** I made the code safer by adding some error checking.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell: CellSort = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CellSort
    // ^ Capitalize your class names!!!

    if let cell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CellSort {
        // Success

        cell.type.font = UIFont(name: "System-Bold", size: 17)
        cell.typeselected.hidden = false
        print("selected")
        print(sort[indexPath.row])
    }
    else{
        // Error; Either: 
        //     A) Cell was not found at the specified index
        //        path (method returned nil), or
        //
        //     B) The returned cell (UITableViewCell) could 
        //        not be cast to your custom subclass (CellSort).
        //
        // Neither should happen, if you register your cell classes 
        // correctly and call the above method on the same index path 
        // that was selected.
    }
}
```